# Android Monkeyrunner API Communication from Web Interface (Javascript)

Tags: android

The monkeyrunner tool provides an API for writing programs that control an Android device or emulator from outside of Android code. We have just tried that using python script it works fine on command line. Now our requirement is to provide a web GUI to communicate monkeyrunner bu clicking the buttons on the web GUI. Later it will extended to the remote access also. I just want know the possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already your python scripts doing what you intend to do just add a web presentation layer and invoke these scripts with the corresponding parameter.
The devices and/or emulators should be connected to your web server or you may use adb over wifi, but this is unreliable sometimes.

On the other hand, if you prefer to do everything from java you may take a look at [android: using monkey from java](http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/2011/11/android-using-monkey-from-java.html).